# show grouped product stock on category page

Tags: stock, grouped-products, category-products

Is it possible to show grouped product stock on the category page?

I have tried looping through the collection of grouped products and echoing it to the product category page, but it will spit out on every single product because of the structure of the product loops;

Here is my code that works grabbing the associated product stock inventory:

```
    <?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
        <?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
        <ul class="products-grid products-grid--max-<?php echo $_columnCount; ?>-col">
            <?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
                <?php /*if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
                <?php endif*/ ?>
                <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
                        <?php $_imgSize = 210; ?>
                        <img id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"
                             src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($_imgSize); ?>"
                             alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
                    </a>
                    <div class="product-info">
                        <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>

                        <?php
                            $_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after')->getSortedChildren();
                            foreach($_nameAfterChildren as $_nameAfterChildName):
                                $_nameAfterChild = $this->getChild('name.after')->getChild($_nameAfterChildName);
                                $_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_product);
                        ?>
                            <?php echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml(); ?>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>

                        <?php //echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>

<!-- THIS IS MY MODIFICATION TO OUTPUT STOCK INVENTORY -->

                        <?php  $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                                ->getCollection()
                                ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'grouped'));

                                foreach ($products as $product) {
                                    $associatedProducts = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProducts($product);
                                    foreach($associatedProducts as $singleProduct){
                                        $product_Id = $singleProduct->getId();
                                        $stockLevel = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product_Id)->getQty();
                                        if( $_product->getTypeId() == 'grouped' ){
                                            echo "In Stock: " .$stockLevel. "<br/>";
                                        }
                                    }
                                }               
                        ?>

<!-- THIS IS THE END OF MY MODIFICATION TO OUTPUT STOCK INVENTORY -->

                        <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <div class="actions">
                            <?php if($_product->isSaleable() && !$_product->canConfigure()): ?>
                            <div class="stockamount">In Stock: <?php $qty = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty(); echo $qty; ?></div>
                                <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                            <?php elseif($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                <a title="<?php echo $this->__('View Details') ?>" class="button" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('View Details') ?></a>
                            <?php else: ?>
                                <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <ul class="add-to-links">
                                <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                                    <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                                    <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php /*if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==$_collectionSize): ?>
                <?php endif*/ ?>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </ul>
```

Comment: No answer at this moment but just a small note. Code like this requires a lot of resources on the server. You might want to consider if it's worth it

Comment: Yeah I noticed that the load time was SIGNIFICANTLY longer when I implemented this.

Comment: You're doing about 4 queries joining ~ 10 tables or more. If your shop has high traffic moments your MySQL server will be on fire :) I would not advice it